# Strapi-Mongodb return with empty array from upload_file collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, strapi

upload.js file:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Upload_file = require('../models/upload.model');

router.route('/upload_file').get((req, res) => {
    Upload_file.find()
        .then(upload_file => res.json(upload_file))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

upload.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const upload_fileSchema = new Schema({
    upload_file: {
        _id: String,
        name: String,
        url: String,
        mime: String
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

const Upload_file = mongoose.model('Upload_file', upload_fileSchema);

module.exports = Upload_file;
```

Other collections work perfect, but when I want to get the files json the array is empty, but I have more than one documents in the collection.

Comment: What is the name of the collection in MongoDB? Is it `Upload_file` or `upload_files`

Comment: upload_file is the name

Comment: Mongoose will lower case and pluralize the collection name provided, so it will be looking for `upload_files` even though you provide `Upload_file` in the code. In order to avoid this pass the collection name as 3rd argument. In your case try  `const Upload_file = mongoose.model('Upload_file', upload_fileSchema, 'upload_file')`. Please node MongoDB collection names are case sensitive;
`